# SQL C# Booking System 3 tables Available Tutors/Rooms at a selected time

Tags: c#, sql

I am trying to display available Tutors and Rooms at a certain date at a certain time.

I have 3 tables Lesson table, Room Table and Tutor Table. I am trying the code below

```
string sqlFormattedDate = DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff");
    db.Cmd = db.Conn.CreateCommand();
    db.Cmd.CommandText = "SELECT RoomNumber FROM RoomTBL WHERE RoomNumber NOT IN (
                          SELECT RoomNumber FROM LessonsTBL Where PupilID   = " + 1 + " AND
                          StartDate = '" + sqlFormattedDate + "')";
        db.Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        while (db.Rdr.Read())
        {
          listBox1.Items.Add(db.Rdr);
        }
        db.Rdr.Close();
```

I keep getting a `System.NullReferenceException` on the db.Rdr, but that works completely fine for all other queries.

I have read around other questions and I came up with this solution which doesn't work.

Comment: BTW look up *Prepared Statements*

Comment: You are executing a non query, how will you get a data reader? Also, [Beware of little bobby tables.](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: I dont know what that means sorry.

Comment: Sorry I have a data reader in my Database class, I use the same code in a method directly above and it works fine

Comment: There must be something else then, if you're using the same working code..Maybe you're missing some line, like the `db.Rdr` (for which you didn't provide any info yet) initialization?

Comment: Why don't you use inner joins instead of sub selete?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding another condition to make sure that the reader has rows available to read:

```
    string sqlFormattedDate = DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff");
    db.Cmd = db.Conn.CreateCommand();
    db.Cmd.CommandText = "SELECT RoomNumber FROM RoomTBL WHERE RoomNumber NOT IN (SELECT RoomNumber FROM LessonsTBL Where PupilID = " + 1 + " AND StartDate = '" + sqlFormattedDate + "')";
    db.Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    if (db.Rdr.HasRows)
    {
      while (db.Rdr.Read())
      {
        listBox1.Items.Add(db.Rdr);
      }
    }   
    db.Rdr.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

ExecuteNonQuery returns the query execution status, to be specific returns The number of rows affected (source : System.Data.Common.DbCommand), try using ExecuteReader which will remove your NullReferenceException

```
string sqlFormattedDate = DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff");
db.Cmd = db.Conn.CreateCommand();
db.Cmd.CommandText = "SELECT RoomNumber FROM RoomTBL WHERE RoomNumber NOT IN (SELECT RoomNumber FROM LessonsTBL Where PupilID = " + 1 + " AND StartDate = '" + sqlFormattedDate + "')";
//db.Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
db.Rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
if (db.Rdr.HasRows)
{
  while (db.Rdr.Read())
  {
    listBox1.Items.Add(db.Rdr);
  }
}   
db.Rdr.Close();
```